# Safe instance overriding

Tags: haskell, overriding, newtype

Suppose there is a type `A` that is instance of class `C`.

If I understand correctly, to override instance implementation it is a common practice to introduce a wrapper `newtype A' = A' A`, and then wrap all occurences of `A` in a `A'`.

But then how to ensure that you not accidentally forgot to wrap some `A`s, and that all `A`s use new implementation?

Can we do something about it?

Answer (score 1):

If your function relies on your own implementation of `C` as provided by `A'`, you can just express it in the type signature of that function. So instead of having

```
fGeneric :: C a => a -> b
```

you would just use

```
fSpecific :: A' -> b
```

so you known which behavior you'll get.

Comment: Yes, it is my implementation, but it then consumed by library functions, which I can't change.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out if certain monomorphic types contain `A` that isn't inside the wrapper `A'` by recursively calling `Language.Haskell.TH.reify`. Here's an example of such a mess: http://lpaste.net/94105. This will fail if:

- `reify` does not provide the information needed. Sometimes it doesn't provide the definition that corresponds to the given Name.
- types that contain the instance for A, but don't have to mention the type like `HiddenA` below

  ```
  data HiddenA = forall a. C a => HiddenA a
  instance C HiddenA where f (HiddenA x) = f x
  ```
- there's no guarantee that you actually apply the check to functions you use

But at least it's a compile-time check.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know such things are possible with haskell. But as you've said, now one should remember to apply the check. Thank you.